# What does it mean by "book has legs"?

Tags: idioms

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1371111/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)

I really don't get it by reading weird lines.

> Suddenly the book has legs and Cavendish is rolling in money from
>   royalties.

What does it mean by "book has legs"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/legs#legs_3) has a dictionary entry that explains this quite well:

> legs (*pl. n*.) the ability of a product, advertisement, idea, book etc. to continue to be successful and interest people for a long time

So it means the book had sudden success and popularity. I suppose one could say something similar about Rowling's *Harry Potter* series.

I can see why this would be tricky if you aren't familiar with the expression. It's a figurative expression; the idea is that legs can carry something for some distance.